# How do I customize the layout of a ListBox's ItemsPanelTemplate?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, itemspaneltemplate

I'd like to specify multiple columns for my `ListBox`, but my googling skills have failed me on this one.

How can I modify the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of a `ListBox` to customize the columns displayed?

*Edit: forgot to put what I'd tried already*

I've tried the code

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Which works except I lose the vertical scrollbar

Comment: What control are you looking to modify the `ItemsPanelTemplate` for?

Comment: A `ListBox`, though only because that's what Blend autogenerated for me...I want to display items from a list in a grid, like a less sophisticated Zune album-art view.

Comment: Do you actually need the selection capabilities of a `ListBox`? If not, I'd suggest switching to an `ItemsControl`, and I have some [ItemsControl Examples](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) on my blog that include an example about setting the `ItemsPanelTemplate`

Comment: I want the selection capabilities, yeah - it's my intent to bind another control to the ListBox.Selected property to show more details about the selected item

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're doing with the columns? Are you trying to set up multiple columns in your items, like a DataGrid, or are you trying to lay out the items themselves horizontally and then wrapping vertically?

Comment: @JohnBowen I think I'm trying to lay the items horizontally and then wrap them vertically.

Comment: The small snippet you listed should work for what you want provided the rest of your XAML is correct, but without seeing more it's impossible to know where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It shoudln't be that difficult but it depends - if you are using a grid or some-such control for each item and you don't mind the columns not being the same width with variable width items inside them, then just adding a grid to the ItemTemplate will do.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SomeControl Grid.Column="0" />
            <SomeControl Grid.Column="1" />
            <SomeControl Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The only problem is if you want the grid columns to all be the same size with variable sized content - in which case it would be a little more involved - otherwise you can either explicitly set a size, or let the content decide the size by setting the column widths to `"Auto"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of what I think you're looking for, with 3 columns, item wrapping, and automatic vertical scrolling which will work depending on the surrounding layout.

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border MinHeight="150" Margin="5" Background="Green" CornerRadius="4">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <System:String>One</System:String>
    <System:String>Two</System:String>
    <System:String>Three</System:String>
    <System:String>Four</System:String>
    <System:String>Five</System:String>
    <System:String>Six</System:String>
    <System:String>Seven</System:String>
    <System:String>Eight</System:String>
    <System:String>Nine</System:String>
    <System:String>Ten</System:String>
</ListBox>
```